# spark.executor.extraClassPath option setting programmatically through SparkConf

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

My project jars are conflicting with jars which are on EMR so to fix this 
I have copied all my advanced jars to custom location of nodes through bootstrap script. I have verified jars got copied on to all executor nodes.

It is working fine with spark-submit , my `code` referring new jars which are in custom folder of all nodes.

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit --conf="spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/customJars/*" --conf="spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/customJars/*"
```

Same thing I want to implement programmatically in the code by updating sparkconf object.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/customJars/*");
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/usr/customJars/*");
```

it is not working when I want to implement programmatically. my `code` is not referring updated jars in custom location .

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Most properties cannot be changed at Runtime in Spark.

You can see the documentation for SparkConf: [SparkConf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkConf)

> Once SparkConf is passed to the SparkContext constructor, the values
>   are cloned and cannot be changed. This is a Spark limitation.

You need to make sure that you stop and start your Spark Session before testing new property changes.

As an additional comment from the documentation: [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

For `spark.executor.extraClassPath`:

> Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of executors. This
>   exists primarily for backwards-compatibility with older versions of
>   Spark. Users typically should not need to set this option.

You can use `spark.jars` that will affect the driver and executors:

> Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor
>   classpaths. Globs are allowed.

Make sure that your jars are available in the executors.